# ALTFP_ADD_SUB megafunction in ALTERA

Tags: vhdl

I have the following entity calling the add_sub megafunction created by megafunction wizard under Quartus II :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

library altera_mf;
use altera_mf.altera_mf_components.all;

entity fp_adder is
  port(clock : in std_logic; 
       dataa : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 DOWNTO 0);
         datab : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 DOWNTO 0);
           result : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 DOWNTO 0));
end fp_adder;

architecture fp_adder_impl of fp_adder is
begin
  add: altfp_add_sub 
    generic map(width_exp   => 8, width_man => 23)
    port map(clock => clock, dataa => dataa, datab => datab, 
        result => result);  
end fp_adder_impl;
```

The code synthesises fine but when I launch a waveform to simulate it I always end up with an empty result output. Is there anything I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0):

The ModelSim-Altera pre-build libraries do not contain a model for `altfp_add_sub`, which is probably the reason why it cannot simulate right away.

Take a look at [Floating-Point Megafunctions User Guide](http://www.altera.com/literature/ug/ug_altfp_mfug.pdf?GSA_pos=3&WT.oss_r=1&WT.oss=ALTFP_ADD_SUB%20modelsim) page 27 / 4-4, where the reference to "altfp_add_sub_ex_msim.zip (ModelSim-Altera files)" probably points to the megafunction files that you must compile to get a simulation model for `altfp_add_sub`.